# Keycloak realm/client change management

Tags: authentication, oauth, keycloak, liquibase

I am using KeyCloak as my user management tool, and love it.

The data of Keycloak is stored for me on a Postgres database. Over time, more clients are being registered, and other alterations to the realms may be done. My question is: How do I properly keep track of that, and propagate automatically changes between my different environments? For databases, I use liquibase for a purpose like this. I couldn't find anything similar for the Keycloak case.

So, I wanted to ask: How are you folks out there handling this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're doing the management of those changes. There are generally two approaches:

- Using the Keycloak admin console
- Using the Keycloak CLI

If you're applying your changes via the admin console, then you can either rely on the database backup or setup a scheduled pipeline in your CI tool to make an export of the Keycloak realm into a file and archive it somewhere.

In case you're using the second approach, then you can have a git repository containing all the Keycloak CLI scripts that you run on your server (e.g. to add a client, to update a realm config, etc.). In that case, you can have them reviewed, versioned and then run as part of an automated pipeline. This will also allow you to run a script on different environments. But of course it comes with a price which is to write a script for every single task that you can typically do in admin console with a couple of clicks.

Comment: Yeah, the cli and a bunch of scripts is what I was already thinking as well. The issue is just that this sounds like something that could/should be stream-lined in one tool, and I was wondering if there is something I was missing or a process in an open-source-project that I could adapt.

Comment: I also found it quite annoying. We rely on the first approach in our organization and of course we don't need to run the same script on multiple environments.

Comment: I happened on this as I've recently been pondering the same question. Definitely think that a history of migration scripts using the admin cli is the most CI friendly approach... after all, it's how we manage database schema changes